# C++: "Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction" Error

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, vector

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? I'm trying to create a program that outputs the alternating sum of a vector of integers. For example, if the input is 1 2 3 4, then the result would be 1-2+3-4 = -2. The program will also continue to run if the user enters "y" and stops when the user enters "n".

I understand that there are syntax errors in my code: when inputting the integers as a vector and when calling the alternating_sum function. Still, I don't know how to fix it.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double alternating_sum(vector<int> numbers)
{
    double sum = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) // i = position in vector
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)     // if i is even
        {
            sum += numbers[i];
        }
        else                // if i is odd
        {
            sum -= numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    char response;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter a list of integers: ";
        cin >> vector<int> input;

        double result = alternating_sum(vector<int> input);

        cout << "Continue (y/n)? ";
        cin >> response;

        if (response == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the syntax errors? What line do they appear on?

Comment: line 32: cin >> vector<int> input; and line 34: double result = alternating_sum(vector<int> input);

Comment: @CatherineJennifer -- If the issue is with inputting values, shouldn't that be the focus, and not the calculation?  Create a small program that inputs values one by one into a vector, and only does that job.  If you have trouble with that, then you can focus on asking questions.  The calculation code throws people off in believing the issue is with the calculation.

Comment: `cin >> vector<int> input;` [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know why you are declaring a variable inside an input statement.

Comment: @scohe001 I was so lazy to point out all those mistake OPs code, rather I can give a simple fix and would suggest him to read about something about std::vector<>.

Comment: @CatherineJennifer I believe this is more than a syntax issue -- inputting values into a vector will look nothing like the code you attempted.  I think you should write small programs first that do the basics.  The first thing is to write a small program that simply inputs values in a vector.  There are plenty of links here and other places that shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there's a lot to fix. To name the first that comes to mind, `cin >> vector<int> input;` you're declaring a variable in an input statement, but also you can't `cin >>` to a vector, it doesn't work syntactically.

You have to loop to get every number input the user has provided, and put it into the array that way. For that you would write something like:

```
vector<int> v;
int input;
while (cin >> input)
     v.push_back(input);
```

The reason for this is `cin >>` really only eats the first input value until it sees whitespace or `EOF`, so if you entered something like `1 2 3 4 5` the line `cin >> input` would only grab the value `1` on the first call.

Answer (score 0):

```
 double result = alternating_sum(vector<int> input);
```

you need to also write this as

```
double result = alternating_sum(input);
```

Since input is already defined no need to do it again :)

Also @samualnj gave you the other answer!

all the best and keep coding :D